# php - загрузить список тестов из папки, вывести красиво выбранный тест (он в json) в html

Tags: php, json

Ребята, только начинаю в этом всем разбираться, очень нужна помощь.
Мне нужно создать три пхп-файла: admin.php, list.php и test.php.
На админе я могу посмотреть список доступных тестов по ссылке (list.php) и в форме загрузить свой. А test.пхп выводит тест (он обязательно в json) красиво, со всякими radio). При этом считает количество правильных ответов.
Поскольку я совсем новичок - моей соображалки хватило пока только на написание admin (могу загрузить корректный json-файл, код не привожу). List тоже готов))

```
<?php
    $files_dir = "./tests";
    $files_list = scandir($files_dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($files_list as $value)
    {
        if ($value !='.' and $value !='..' ) 
        {
            echo '<li><a href="./tests'. $value.'">'.$value.'</a></li><br>';
        }
        else{}
    }
    echo '</ol>';
?>
```

И все. Не понимаю, каким образом писать list, чтобы при выборе пользователем из списка тестов на странице открывался действительно корректный тест. Не понимаю логику подобных процессов на php. И как писать сам test.php?

Answer (score 1):

Пусть у Вас есть некий массив тестов (это может быть массив, список файлов, записи в БД - не принципиально). И каждый тест имеет некий уникальный идентификатор

```
$tests = [
  1 => ['name' => 'Test1', 'test' => '{test1}'],
  2 => ['name' => 'Test2', 'test' => '{test2}'],
  3 => ['name' => 'Test3', 'test' => '{test3}']
];
```

тогда в `list.php` Вам нужно пробежаться по этому массиву, и вывести все тесты, со ссылкой на `test.php` и передачей идентификатора теста в виде GET-параметра

```
foreach ($tests as $id => $test)
  printf('<a href="test.php?id=%s>%s</a>', $key, $test['name']);
```

А в `test.php` проанализировать введенный параметр и вывести нужный тест

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']) || !isset($tests[$_GET['id']]))
  die('Invalid test id');
$test = $tests[$_GET['id']];
showTest($test['test']);
```

Конкретно для Вашего случая, Вам нужно строку

> ```
> echo '<li><a href="./tests'. $value.'">'.$value.'</a></li><br>';
> ```

заменить на

```
echo '<li><a href="test.php?name='. $value.'">'.$value.'</a></li><br>';
```

и с анализом

```
if(!isset($_GET['name']) || !file_exists('./tests/' . $_GET['name']))
  die('Invalid test name');
$test_file_name = $_GET['name'];
................
```